# JavaScript function not recognizing correct password

Tags: javascript, html, src

I was playing an online [game](https://0xf.at/play/10) where you have to find the password by viewing the page source (or inspect element). I am confused my this line `if(el.value == ""+CodeCode+"")`. `el.value` is my guess, and it says I can continue if my guess is: `""+CodeCode+""`. "+CodeCode+" is defined as: `"+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit";` but i tried "0xf.at_hackit" (with and without quotes but it is not working). I have been stuck on this for 2 hours so please help!

Here is  the  code of the game which has a javascript function:

```
     <!-- :::::::::::::::::==== GAME STARTS HERE ====::::::::::::::::: -->
        <h1>Level 10</h1>
        <p>Try not to be fooled</p>
        <input id="pw" type="password" />
        <br/><input type="button" value="OK" onClick="checkPW()"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">var CodeCode = "moo6be";

            function checkPW()
            {
                "+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit";
                var el = document.getElementById("pw");
                if(el.value == ""+CodeCode+"")
                    document.location.href="?pw="+el.value;
                else alert("Wrong password");
            }

        </script>
    <!-- ::::::::::::::::::==== GAME ENDS HERE ====:::::::::::::::::: -->
```

Comment: No, `==` is not defining. `CodeCode` is defined as `"moo6be"`. That equality check doesn’t do anything.

Comment: yes enter the password as: moo6be

Comment: @Xufox `"moo6be"` worked! Can you explain how?

Comment: @RohanShake Didn’t I already explain it in my comment?

Comment: `var CodeCode = "moo6be";`

Comment: So, what is your specific programming question here? What kind of answer do you actually expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is assigned right after the `<script>` tag.

The line `"+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit";` does nothing, its just expression that evaluates to false (comparing two different strings), but no assignment, so no side effects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var CodeCode = "moo6be"; // <==== HERE 

    function checkPW() {
        "+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit";       // <==== this does nothing, its just expression that evaluates to false, but no assignment
        var el = document.getElementById("pw");
        if(el.value == ""+CodeCode+"")         // <==== this is the same as `if(el.value == CodeCode)`
            document.location.href="?pw="+el.value;
        else alert("Wrong password");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, because of you and JohnD's answers, I understand that `""+CodeCode+""` is `"" + CodeCode + ""`. I will accept asap

Comment: It's the same as using just the variable `CodeCode` (it would also cast it to string, but it was already a string, so its equal).

Comment: I know but when I first looked at it I was confused by: `"+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit"` and i frankly didn't see: `var CodeCode = "moo6be";`

Answer (score 1):

`""+CodeCode+""` is the same thing as: `"" + CodeCode + ""`

CodeCode is assigned right after the  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var CodeCode = "moo6be"; // HERE

function checkPW()
        {
            "+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit"; // this does nothing, its just expression that evaluates to false - this is meant to trick you
            var el = document.getElementById("pw");
            if(el.value == ""+CodeCode+"")
                document.location.href="?pw="+el.value;
            else alert("Wrong password");
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `moo6be`.

This is because `"+CodeCode+" == "0xf.at_hackit";` has double equals, which just means it is a comparison statement (which will just evaluate to false). It is important to note that this is unrelated to the rest of the program.

The main line here is: `if(el.value == ""+CodeCode+"")`.

Which is: `"" (empty string)` `+` `CodeCode (moo6be)` `+` `"" (empty string)`.

Comment: Have no any idea... I answered first and exactly the same as other answers after me. It happens, I think.

Comment: Your formatting is kinda confusing - but i think a high rep user was probably trying to answer the question themselves... Everything on SO gets down-voted these days

Comment: Rep is overrated ;) Glad that you get the answer anyway.